# Add alt tags to image - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to search for all the  tag in every content type that I have. After searching, I want to add alt tag (if missing) to each. 
Is there any module available to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never have heard about such a module, the most closest one is [SEO Compliance Checker](http://drupal.org/project/seo_checker) but it checks node content only upon its creation or modification.

Here is some thoughts on how you can achieve that without using any custom module:

1. Manually checking out your database via phpMyAdmin and sorting tables' rows by `field_yourimg_alt` field so you can easily find where its value is missing.
2. Create a new View where output all you images (or hide them, if there are dozens of images) with its alt tags (outputting alt tag as a plain text will be available in replacement patterns in configuration of your field). So when you'll output all your images with its alt tags it'll be easy to notice images without this tag. Also, to make it even simpler you can output your fields as a sortable table, so all images with missing alt tag will be at the top of the list (or you can try to add a specific sort criteria in your View, not sure for certain but I hope it will work). It'll be just perfect to output only images which do not have alt tag, but right now I don't know how to do that, sorry.
3. Create your own module.

So I guess if you manage not very large site and need to check alt tags only once, the #1 tip would be a good choice. If it's necessary to check alt tags on regular basis and/or you have dozens of images, try to play with Views in order to create just what you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton tulvit. Your suggestion about creating a view certainly did work and works like charm.